# Access VBA DMin mutliple criteria, Type mismatch error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to find the smallest ID value that is not owned by the current user and does not have a date. The first two statements work but when I join them together i get the mismatch error. ID is the key, userid as string, intialreviewdate as date, logid as long.

```
logid = DMin("ID", "tbl_QRCLDB_data", "[IntialReviewDate] Is Null")
logid = DMin("ID", "tbl_QRCLDB_data", "[CommLogOwner]<> '" & UserID & "'")
logid = DMin("ID", "tbl_QRCLDB_data", "[CommLogOwner]<>'" & UserID & "'" And " 
[IntialReviewDate] is Null")
```

Any guidance or suggestions appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
logid = DMin("ID", "tbl_QRCLDB_data", "[CommLogOwner]<>'" & UserID & "' And  
[IntialReviewDate] is Null")
```

Comment: two quotes... i'm almost in tears at how much time i've spent trying to get this. Thank you SunKinight

Comment: @Nick If this solved your problem, please mark it solve by clicking the checkmark on the answer - This let's others know you no longer need assistance. Thanks!